# how does h2o.randomforest handle missing values

Tags: r, random-forest, h2o

After my research on h2o, I have found that h2o.randomForest can handle missing values in variables unlike R randomForest package.

See, http://h2o.ai/blog/2014/04/sjsu-tutorial-h2o-random-forest/

But, after looking everywhere, I can not seem to find how exactly missing values are handled by h2o.randomForest? How similar is it to handling of missin values by R gbm() package?

Any help regarding above 2 questions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the H2O documentation to see how the DRF algorithm handles missing values in various situations:
http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-slater/5/docs-website/h2o-docs/index.html#Data%20Science%20Algorithms-DRF-FAQ

In terms of R's GBM, they create trees that are ready to handle NA's. In other words, it explicitly handles NA's as a special case. R's GBM actually handles NAs as a special case and builds tree branches for them: left, right, NA is the result of every decision.

Hope this helps!

Avni